# How to reload a game in Phaser 3?

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I did reload a game in phaser 3 by this code

```
 playbtn.on('click', (event) => {
        this.scene.restart();
        
    });
```

However, I got a problem then. My game didn't receive any input as an event which means the character just stood stiff, I couldn't control him at all. I don't know if I have to remove that 'click' event of playbtn or something like that. Phaser is completely new to me, any advice or solution would help me a lots. Thank you

Comment: Check out this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-BSz_FeWfkY
Its about going back to the preload.

Comment: Oh many thanks, this is exactly what I've been looking for.